# What is the minimum or maximum amount of trained data is used to train a classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naive-bayes-classifier, training

what should be the min or max size of trained datasets should be used to feed a classifier ? can we use 1 GB or more data as trained data to feed a classifier for jvm related ML frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking it in terms of GBs, unless you're asking about the physical limits of JVM, my suggested approach towards this question would be to plot the cross-validated accuracy vs. the number of rows used in the modelling dataset through stratified sampling. You might observe a point of diminishing return where additional rows do not contribute towards higher accuracy.

In addition, breadth-wise in terms of the number of variables used, you could plot a variable importance plot and plot the cross-validated accuracy vs. the top X important variables. In this case, you might even observe that accuracy increases when you use fewer variables as the noisy variables are discarded. You could then select the top X variables that give you the highest cross-validated accuracy.